# Cannot send or receive SMS on my Moto G XT 1033 (1st Gen) on Cyanogenmod 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, motorola-moto-g

I cannot send or receive SMS on my Moto G XT 1033 (1st Generation) on Cyanogenmod 13 official build. It's a dual SIM phone and only one SIM is working now. This is th first time I'm rooting and installing a custom ROM. I can receive and make calls but not SMS.  I just flashed CM13 along with GApps.

Comment: PLS HELP DEAR FRIENDS..

Comment: If you want a usable phone with Cyanogenmod then consider using the latest snapshot instead of a nighty. Cyanogenmod 13 builds are still too early to be able to use on a daily basis, unless you have a nexus device of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this patch, it is a modem image:

1. Reboot your phone into bootloader
2. Extract the contents of [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXfCy9iDr_gQ2FrZjdmYUdJS0U/view)
3. Run **Fix CM13 Network XT1033.bat**

Original post can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63499113&postcount=511)

Comment: This is an "Okay" answer, but could you consider reproducing why this procedure should work from the link in your answer, in case the link dies in the future?